# How to use greenorg.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0 without jcenter repo?

Tags: gradle, greendao

`jcenter` repo is deprecated, so I'd like to migrate from it. Unfortunatelly `org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0` is published only here.

How can I use it without `jcenter`?

Answer (score 4):

The plugin is also published to Central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.greenrobot/greendao-gradle-plugin

```
// settings.gradle

pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == 'org.greenrobot.greendao') {
                useModule('org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0')
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // Use Maven Central in addition to Gradle plugin portal
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

--

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
}
```

Comment: I found that I had to use `if (requested.id.id == 'org.greenrobot.greendao')...` in order to get this answer to work. Thank you, regardless; I wouldn't have known how to get this working otherwise!